# Set Windows Form background color as Blend color?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Very new to Visual basic, and I need to set the background color of a Windows Form as a `ColorBlend` this is what I have so far. How do I finish it off?

```
Dim col As New ColorBlend
Dim myColours As Color() = {Color.Red, Color.Green}
col.Colors = myColours
Me.BackColor
```

I know this may seem a bit futile, but I need it for an assignment. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a gradient?

Comment: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/use-a-lineargradientbrush-in-c/ has an example of drawing a rectangle filled from a `ColorBlend`.  You'll have to convert it from C# to vb.net though.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works perfectly for me :

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal pevent As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        'Define starters (the point [0,0] is the top-left corner of the form)
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        'Define the dimension (here it depends on your form dimension)
        Dim wid As Integer = Me.Width
        Dim hgt As Integer = Me.Height

        Dim red_green_brush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(x, y), New Point(x + wid, y), Color.Red, Color.Green)
        ' ColorBlend.
        pevent.Graphics.DrawString("ColorBlend", Me.Font, Brushes.Red, x, y)
        y += 15
        Dim color_blend As New ColorBlend(2)
        color_blend.Colors = New Color() {Color.Red, Color.Green}
        color_blend.Positions = New Single() {0.0, 1.0}
        red_green_brush.InterpolationColors = color_blend
        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(red_green_brush, x, y, wid, hgt)
        red_green_brush.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to do somebody's homework then at least do it correctly so he won't get a failing grade.  This is only a D, override OnPaintBackground() instead.

Comment: ...and dispose your brush.

Comment: I edited my post. Thank you for your replies, i'm still learning the langage too :)